# Statements cannot exist outside of methods?

Tags: c#, methods, terminology

Reading a book (VS 2010), it says that commands (statements) in .NET Csharp cannot exist outside of method.
I am wondering - field declaration etc, these are commands, are they not? And they exist at class level. Can somebody elaborate at this a bit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no such concept as a "command" in C#.

And a static / instance variable declaration isn't categorized as a statement within C# - it's a *field-declaration* (which is a type of *class-member-declaration*) as per the C# spec. See section 10.5 of the [C# 4 spec](http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/B/D/0BDA894F-2CCD-4C2C-B5A7-4EB1171962E5/CSharp%20Language%20Specification.doc) for example.

Now the statements which declare *local* variables are statements, as defined by *declaration-statement* in the spec (section 8.5). They're only used for locals though. See section B.2.5 for a complete list of statement productions within C# 4.

Basically, the C# spec defines the terminology involved - so while you might think *informally* of "commands" and the like, in a matter of correctness the C# spec is the source of authority. (Except for where it doesn't say what the language designers meant to say, of course. That's pretty rare.)

Comment: And what about declaration with initialization?

Comment: @Miria: That's still part of a *field-declaration*, but it's not a statement. It could use a lambda expression which in turn could *contain* statements, mind you...

Comment: Thanks! It confused me as the book says int A=5 is statement and so you must not forget to write semicolon..

Comment: @Miria: It's a statement when it's with in a method (a declaration-statement). It's not a statement when it's just a class member.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean:

```
class Foo
{
    int count = 0;
    StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
}
```

The count and buffer are declarations using initializer *expressions* . But this code contains no *statements*.

Answer (score 1):

A field initialiser is written with the code outside a method, but the compiler puts that code inside the constructor.

So a field initialiser like this:

```
class Foo  {

  int Bar = 42;

}
```

is basiclally a field and an initialiser in the constructor:

```
class Foo  {

  int Bar;

  Foo() {
    Bar = 42;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you said they're declarations, a statement is one which actually gets something done.

Comment: Well, a declaration doesn't *have* to just reserve memory - it can include an initializer which does something too. It's still not a statement though.

Answer (score 0):

No, they're declarations. Class member declarations, to be precise.

And it's perfectly legal for those to exist outside of a method. Otherwise, you couldn't declare a method in the first place!

By "statements", the book is telling you that you can't have things like *method calls* outside of a method. For example, the following code is illegal:

```
public void DoSomething()
{
    // Do something here...
}

MessageBox.Show("This statement is not allowed because it is outside a method.");
```

Answer (score 0):

Classes, namespace, fields declarations are not declarations statements.

A field can be initialised outside a method with an *expression* but while an expression is a statement there are lots of statements that are not expressions (eg. `if`).

It all comes down to how the language grammar defines the terms, and the way C# does it is pretty common (eg. very similar to C and C++).